# break on @ symbol in table cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have a table that often overruns the width of the page.  I figured out that if I format the cells as paragraphs with a set width then LaTeX will wrap the contents of the cell.  However, the column that needs this most is the one with email addresses in it.  Because email addresses don't have spaces they won't wrap within the cell.  I would like to make it break and wrap before the @ symbol in the email address.  I can't find anything online about how to do this.

```
\begin{longtabu}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{City} & \textbf{State/Province} & \textbf{Phone} & \textbf{Email}
\\
\hline
\raggedright
\nohyphens{Doe, John} &
\raggedright
\nohyphens{Electrical Engineer} &
\raggedright
\nohyphens{New York} &
\raggedright
\nohyphens{New York} &
555-555-5555 & 
john_doe@really_long_email_address.com
\\
\hline
\end{longtabu}
```

Comment: `url` package and `\url{john_doe@really_long_email_address.com}` is one possibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`url` package and

```
\url{john_doe@really_long_email_address.com}
```

is one possibility –